# Changing format of displayed coords. in gnuplot graph box

Tags: gnuplot

Once a data file is plotted, you can go thru the graph with the mouse, to display the x-y value to which the pointer points; those x-y values are shown on the left bottom corner of the graph. Now, my x-values are timedate values, and the x-value displayed at that corner comes in seconds-since-year-2K format, not in day-month-year format. Do you know how to fix that in gnuplot for windows?

Comment: Have you checked the manual? Have you checked `help mouseformat`?

Answer (score 1):

Please check and read `help mouseformat`.

If you `set mouse mouseformat 3` the format will be determined by your setting in `set timefmt`, which can be different what you set via `set format x ...`.

Note, apparently, `reset session` will reset `mouseformat 3` to default date formatting `"%d/%m/%y,%H:%M"`, but not to `mouseformat 1` (axes coordinates) which is the default when starting my wxt terminal window.

**Script:**

```
### change mouseformat
reset session

t0 = time(0)
set xrange[t0:]

set mouse mouseformat 3
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
set format x "%Y\n%m-%d" timedate

plot '+' u (t0+$0*3600*24):0 w lp
### end of script
```

**Result:** (wxt terminal under Windows)

[image]